# Unable to combine multiple arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to combine these two arrays (x and y). These would combine for form array A, But I am getting multiple build errors. First I am getting a "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'" error as well as an expected declaration error. I am not sure how to proceed as this is the first time I've attempted this in Swift. Any guidance would be helpful.

```
var x = [
    "Nation Flags",
    "Landmarks",
    "Smash",
    "History",
    "Famous People",
    "Word Find",
    "Quiz",
    "Test Your Knowledge"]

var y: [AnyObject] = [Int(true), Int(false), Int(true), Int(false), Int(false),Int(false),Int(false),Int(false),]

var challengesArray: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

for (index, value) in x.enumerate() { // <-- here is the new loop
var Challenge: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
"challenge" : x[index],
"status" : y[index]
]

challengesArray.append(Challenge)
}
```

Comment: Sorry was a typo I have amended it to reflect the proper form.

Comment: your code works for me in Playground. maybe avoid C-type loop since it will not be supported in Swift 3.0. `for (index, value) in x.enumerate() { ... }`

Comment: yeah, it worked for me in the playground as well but when i went to implement it I received the errors. So I thought I was doing something wrong. I'm not sure I get what you mean about eliminating the loop, so your suggestion would be to use enumerate rather than the "for var"?

Comment: on which line do you get your error ?

Comment: On the "for var i = 0; i < x.count; i++ {" is where I receive the "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the recommanded way to loop, it will probably not fix your error, but could help:

**you have to wrap the code in a method/function**
you cannot execute for loop in a class declaration.

```
class GameSelectorViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate {

var x = [
    "xxxxx xxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxx xxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx"]

var y: [AnyObject] = [Int(true), Int(false), Int(true), Int(false)]

var A: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

func combineArray() { // <-- here is the function
    for (index, value) in x.enumerate() { // <-- here is the new loop
        var Challenge: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            "challenge" : x[index],
            "status" : y[index]
        ]

        A.append(Challenge)
    }
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.combineArray()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you were right still got the error  "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"  on line "for (index, value) in x.enumerate() {".

Comment: there is something else, this code is working. give us lines above

Comment: I've edited but now get an error of Expected declaration.

Comment: This code works in Playground flawless but in Xcode it throws the expected declaration error.

Comment: the error doesn't come from this code, it's somewhere else, please provide full code in order to help you.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: you cannot execute for loop, outside a `func`, look at my update

Comment: Dang I feel so dumb right now your exactly right! Thanks your help is greatly appreciated. I feel like I owe you one really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

C-style `for` loop has been deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3. Don't use it for new code. Also, acquaint yourself with Swift's higher-order functions. Give this a try:

```
var x = [
    "xxxxx xxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxx xxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx"]

var y = [Int(true), Int(false), Int(true), Int(false)]

let A = zip(x ,y).map { ["challenge": $0, "status": $1] }
```

Comment: Instance member 'x' cannot be used on type 'UIViewController' I am assuming cause its a string array. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There is code that you are not showing here so sorry can't help with that